# Placing event listeners on individual cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to create an extension from chrome which monitors a specified cookie and takes action when its value is overwritten. I'm aware that the [cookies library](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged) has an onChanged() event listener but I don't know how to use for specific cookies.

For example, if I visit google.com, it stores a cookie called "NID"-- how do I make an event listener specifically for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it doesn't seem like you can monitor individual cookies. What you can do, however, is check the cookie after the callback is fired to determine whether to take action.

Since the callback is passed a `changeInfo` parameter containing information about the cookie and the reason for the change, you can just check that and fire another function if necessary.

Comment: I figured as much. I wish the APIs were more developed b/c this is an extremely inefficient algorithm.